# C# foreach statement cannot operate on variables

Tags: c#, variables

I am trying to get value of html document by tag name but when I use foreach I had got a error says "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type object because object does not contain public definition for GetEnumerator"

```
object divs = this.webBrowser1.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("div");
                foreach (HtmlElement d in divs)
                {
                    if ((d.GetAttribute("className") == "_3576"))
                    {
                        this.label2.Text = d.InnerText;
                    }

                }
```

I am trying to use the answer in SOLVED ASK like this :

```
HtmlElement = new divs HtmlElement();
```

Still not working. I just convert the code from VB.net to C# The code work in VB.net well but got error on C#.

The original VB.net code is:

```
 Dim divs = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("div")
        For Each d As HtmlElement In divs
            If d.GetAttribute("className") = "_3576" Then
                Label5.Text = d.InnerText
            End If
 Next
```

Comment: I'd say DON'T cast it to anything...  Keep it as a `HtmlElementCollection`, which itself DOES have a GetEnumerater() method.

Comment: divs is an object, it's not enumeratable. Find the proper return value for GetElementsByTagName and initialize your divs with that.

Comment: @DanRayson Can you teach me how?. I just learned c# by 1 day :(

Comment: @ArGOO What happens if you change `object divs = ...` to `var divs = ...` on the first line?

Comment: As usual, the first thing to do is going to the docs. Surprisingly you could find examples that works also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @ArGOO You can follow bad practice and change `object` to `var`, that'll work.  Best way though is to be explicit, and change `object` to `HtmlElementCollection`, as @Steve pointed out, it's there in the documentation :)

Comment: @thesystem the value of the html not be in labal2.

Comment: Why did you declare `divs` as type `object`? That's not the type that `GetElementsByTagName()` returns.

Comment: @JonathanWood I am not sure why but this code In VB.net Its work like magic. Then I convert to code to c# its got error :(

Comment: @ArGOO: That doesn't sound right, but in any case you should use explicit data types regardless of what language you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A variable of type `object` cannot be enumerated, since it isn't a collection. My guess is that the original VB.NET code looked something like this:

```vb
Dim divs = Me.WebBrowser1.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("divs")
```

which means that the type of the variable is *inferred* (the compiler specifies it for you).

The equivalent C# code would be declaring it as `var`:

```
var divs = this.webBrowser1.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("divs");
```

Or you can also skip the inferring and declare it explicitly:

```
HtmlElementCollection divs = this.webBrowser1.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("divs");
```

Comment: I have done changing but the value of html that appear in vb.net does not appear in C#.

Comment: @ArGOO : That can be hard for us to diagnose as it depends on whether the `d.GetAttribute("className") == "_3576"` check passes, but please show us the original VB.NET code so we can see if there are any other mistakes in the conversion.

Comment: Does the HTML code have multiple "divs" with classname="_3576"? It could just be that C# & VB.Net do not return them in the same order.

Comment: @PaulF Yes Its have multiple divs but only one _3567

Comment: Does the InnerText look anything like what is in the div? Is the the same as some other div? It is very difficult for us to try to work out what is happening without being able to see the input data & the actual & expected output values.

Comment: @ArGOO : I can see no other conversion problems, so the output depends on whether the `d.GetAttribute("className") == "_3576"` check passes, and how many times. We can't help you with that, so you need to use [breakpoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx) and [examine your variables](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/07/15/7-ways-to-look-at-the-values-of-variables-while-debugging-in-visual-studio/) to find that out.

Comment: @VisualVincent Its working I miscorrect "divs" and "div" when I declare div. Sorry

Comment: @ArGOO : Glad to hear you got it working! Good luck with your project!